# NoClassDefFoundError on external library project for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I use eclipse for Google Android development.

I've created a library project (`[x] Is Library` in the Android-settings), which includes an external jar-file (Referenced Libraries). This library project are referenced in another Project (the actual project which will use the library project). This is done by add the project under the Android-settings.

the source compiles but if I want to execute it on the device, I get the NoClassDefFoundError for a class which is **inside the jar-file which is included in the library project**.

**Edit:** The jar-file ist added to the exported entries (`[x] my.jar` on the `Order and Export`-Tab from the library project)

Is there a clean way to get this working?

Comment: are you sure that the not found class is in the referenced jar? there are a number of issues with regular java classes referenced by jars that are in java SE but are not in Dalvik like some javax and all lava.beans classes

Comment: if it is in the jar, have you added the jar to the exported items?

Comment: @kostja: Yes, I've modified my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has been clearly stated in offcial API [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#considerations):

> A library project can include a JAR library
>
> You can develop a library project that itself includes a JAR library, however you need to manually edit the dependent application project's build path and add a path to the JAR file

The jar lib must be manually added to the **dependent application project**'s build path, not only the library project build path itself.

**Update from SDK r17:**

This is automatically handled by ADT now, check out new feature for ADT 17.0.0 release [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes):

> Added feature to automatically setup JAR dependencies. Any .jar files in the /libs folder are added to the build configuration (similar to how the Ant build system works). Also, .jar files needed by library projects are also automatically added to projects that depend on those library projects. ([more info](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects))

Comment: this means that the main project that uses the library project which use the jar file must also have the jar file in the Java Build Path and tick it in Order and Export tab... I spent quite a while adding the projects and jar files to no avail.. build OK but runtime noclassdeffoundexception

Answer (score 7):

For those who followed the steps(even check the projects in "Order and Export") and still have the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in the API 17, the final step is to check that your compiler does not run with Java 1.7. If is 1.7 then you should change it to 1.6 for all your projects. After that it will ask to rebuild all the projects and successfully ran on my phone :)

To change the java compile version in eclipse, this is located in: Project properties > Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance level: 1.6

Comment: why should we need to do this?

Comment: +1 Excellent, this fixed the issue for me. Crazy this should happen in the first place though...

Comment: +1 This worked but in my case, it was that I just needed a rebuild. Thanks. =D

Answer (score 2):

Go to `project properties -> build path-> libraies`

If you see your jar files like this

```
snmp4j.jar - e:\software\jars
```

Its may your problem

Add libs folder in your project and copy jar file in that folder. Right click jar file and go `build path -> add to build path`.  Then you can see your jar as

```
snmp4j.jar  - project_name/libs
```

Its worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had two projects using the same library: one working, the other one crashing with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.
After nothing else helped me, I looked into the file `project.properties` in the root directory of my project.
The working project had the `android.library.reference` line (the last line below), the crashing one did not:

```
# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../my-library-project
```

I manually added the line and it started working!
(Yes, I did try both *(project) properties -- java build path -- projects* and *(project) properties -- java build path -- order and exports* -- nothing helped.)

**PS** By the way, "project properties" has also the "project references" tab. No idea if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a minor issue when I upgraded to ADT17 where my libs weren't being imported properly. Turns out this is because my librarys were being linked as dependancies from my lib folder not libs!

Seems librarys have to be in the libs folder from now

Comment: Had the same. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885971/new-android-sdk-17-issue-in-my-app

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and non of the solutions out here fixed it.

**Short version:** the JAR was compiled in Java `1.7` and could not be found by Dalvik.

We build an internal JAR that we share across backend and mobile clients with Maven. The problem ended up being that the JAR was compiled with Java 1.7. Androids dalvik only supports Java 1.5 and 1.6. This is why everything works fine in Eclipse as it's not compiled to dalvik at this point.

We even [specified the target and source version in the Maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to compile with Java 1.6. This did not work because only JDK 1.7 was installed on the build machine. A small note at the bottom of the Maven page gave us the hint: `Note: Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version.`

To see if you have this problem as well, rename your `*.jar` file to `*.zip` unpack it, and look in the `MANIFEST.MF` file for the `Build-Jdk:` parameter to see what Java version actually compiled your JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to pay attention to is library package names.

If you are using ADT21 and you happen to have libraries that have the same package name, there will be error during compile but it will still compile and run in Eclipse, giving you an APK that is missing some of the resource classes. Hence the crash when you run the app.

If you compile it with ANT then you can see the compile error that says two or more libraries use the same package name.

To fix this, rename your library project by using Android Tools -> Rename Application Package. Then everything will go back to normal.

It took me almost entire day to figure this out...