# New android SDK 17 issue in my app?

Tags: android, performance, sdk

Today i was update my android sdk to new android adk-17 . 
i am facing some problems in this, that is unable to show AddMob in my app, if i remove addmob in the code able to run the app without any errors otherwise not. what is the solution for this, is this bug in new sdk.

this is the Logcat information

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader   
           dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.veritra.iflipout-1.apk]
```

Comment: check out this link http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the ADK update has messed-up with your project's build-path.
Try removing the admob JAR and add it again to your `libs` folder, add it to your Build Path and do a Clean Project.

Anyway it's hard to help you without more details on the error you encounter.

**EDIT** following poster's comment about not having a `libs` folder:

You should try this:

1. Remove all references to the AdMob JAR in your project -> your code should not build without error anymore
2. Create à `libs` folder at the root of your project
3. Copy the AdMob JAR into the `libs` folder
4. Make sure this AdMob JAR is in your Build Path (this will allow your code to build wihtout error)
5. (If still not running OK) Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Comment: i think you might have written "lib" folder  instead of "libs" coz this solution is working for me.

Comment: For those who followed the steps(even check the projects in "Order and Export") and still have the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in the API 17, the final step is to check that your compiler does not run with Java 1.7. If is 1.7 then you should change it to 1.6 for all your projects. After that it will ask to rebuild all the projects and successfully ran on my phone :)

To change the java compile version, this is located in: Project proerties > Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance level: 1.6. Please, can you add this optional step? Java 1.7 is the default version in the latest Linux distros.

Answer (score 2):

The 'problem' here is that the SDK is a lot more strict about the libraries. If you do not check the library as 'exported' in eclipse, it is not added to your APK, leading to this nasty class not found exception. You should mark your libraries as exported.

```
Project Properties | Java Build Path | Order and Export
```

Comment: You are the **man**! The above answer doesn't include that hint. But this was really important to me. Now he is exporting the libs! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

when I updated my SDK it was total mess. Well, the only I had to change was the PATH in Environment Variables.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html :

> Adding both tools/ and platform-tools/ to your PATH lets you run command line tools without needing to supply the full path to the tool directories. Depending on your operating system, you can include these directories in your PATH in the following way:
>   On Windows, right-click on My Computer, and select Properties. Under the Advanced tab, hit the Environment Variables button, and in the dialog that comes up, double-click on Path (under System Variables). Add the full path to the tools/ and platform-tools/ directories to the path.
>   On Linux, edit your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc file. Look for a line that sets the PATH environment variable and add the full path to the tools/ and platform-tools/ directories to it. If you don't see a line setting the path, you can add one:
>   export PATH=${PATH}:/tools:/platform-tools
>   On a Mac OS X, look in your home directory for .bash_profile and proceed as for Linux. You can create the .bash_profile if you don't already have one.