# eclipse adt 17 and the libs folder

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Ok so i update to eclipse adt to version 17 and I get this error

```
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.galeola.agentis/com.galeola.agentis.activity.GestionaleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.galeola.agentis.activity.GestionaleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.galeola.agentis-1.apk]
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1742)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.galeola.agentis.activity.GestionaleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.galeola.agentis-1.apk]
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1733)
04-05 12:28:55.810: E/AndroidRuntime(5470):     ... 11 more
```

however if i move my libraries to /libs i can start the applications, but with the libraries in /libs javadoc and javasources stops working, while if they are not in /libs javadoc and javasource works, so I don't understand why.

Comment: found it http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=27490

Comment: Good question. I knew about the runtime error if the jars weren't in libs. I hadn't realised until now that the javdocs were broken. I don't agree with the downvote or the vote to close. +1 from me.

Comment: comment 8 of the bug post fixed this for me, but had to read 3 times to get it right

Comment: @max4ever: It fixes the Eclipse build OK, but it breaks my Ant build. I'll have to poke around in the build.xml again to get both javadocs and the Ant build working. I'm not impressed with r17!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is the bug and the solution is comment #8 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c8

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Xavier Ducrohet's answers [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/zAVxRbqw8Fw). But basically, with adt17 you cannot attach Javadoc to your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

For **non library** projects:

As mentioned in the original question comment 8 in [this android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=27490) fixes the build, runtime and javadoc issues, albeit by way of a kludge.

Unfortunately Ant builds are broken. To fix Ant builds which use Proguard, move jars to lib as described in comment 8 and to ant.properties add:

```
jar.libs.dir=lib
```

and to proguard.cfg add:

```
-injars lib
```

The second addition is necessary to fix runtime crashes.

I've not tested this for projects that use instrumentation or emma tasks, but it seems OK for non-library projects where you want both an Eclipse and an Ant build.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ADK update has messed-up with your project's build-path. Try removing the JAR and add it again to your `libs` folder, add it to your Build Path and do a Clean Project.

check my Question once -- [New android SDK 17 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9885971/964741)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hours of research , I found a simple solution.

- Click on your Android Project
- Select Properties
- Select Java Build
- Path Select Order and Export
- Check all your references

Thats all !