# Android multiple project dependencies and size

Tags: android, size, android-library

I got a question about *project library* and *size of an Android application*.

**Let me explain:**

I have a library project, let's call it **A** that is *used in 3 library projects* (**B**, **C** and **D**).

In my Android Application, I have 3 library dependencies (1 for B, 1 for C and 1 for D).

So in fact it looks like this:

[image: application's architecture]

**Then my question is:**

Is the A library project 3 times in my application ? Or just used 1 time for every block that use it (B, C, D, even My Application).

In other words, if the *size of A is 1MB*, does *My application* is *1MB bigger* or *3MB bigger* ? (not exactly but the point is there)

Comment: Maybe this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287321/how-to-include-external-libraries-in-multiple-projects-without-making-multiple-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `A` library is only copied once in your application, and the components and other libraries of your application use it without re-downloading it or copying it. If you check Maven's POM file for example, you will see that: If you have two libraries `A` and `B`, and library `A` is dependent on library `C` and `D` and library B is dependent on C and E, the Maven will see that the library C is already downloaded and included to your project and will not re-download it or copy it whatsoever. Same thing applies to other project management tools from what I know.

Plus when you include more than one times a duplicate code you might see errors such as: `Multiple dex files define ...`

Conclusion: Library A is "only included 1 time in your application".

Comment: Well explained ! Seems logic :) Thanks