# Export a Java library to an Android project and a GWT project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gwt, shared-libraries

I add and remove some classes during editing a Java library project.

E.g., I added the two classes.

1. Dummy1.java
2. Dummy2.java

Then I right-click the source folder (`src` where all the packages are) of my library project and export it to a JAR. I check the 'Export Java source files and resources' checkbox when I export the library.

Then I right-click a client project which uses the library and add the JAR like this.

*Properties > Java Build Path > Tab: Libraries > Add JARs...*

`Dummy1` and `Dummy2` can be used in the project.

After that I add `Dummy3.java` to the library project and modify `Dummy2`, Then I export the library to the JAR again.

Now I can use `Dummy1` and `Dummy2` (except my last modifications) in the client project. `Dummy3` will be accessible after removing and re-adding the JAR to the client project through *Properties*. If I have one or two clients, it'll be OK to add the JAR every time. But if five or seven clients use it, I'll take me a lot of time to remove and re-add after adding a variable to a class of the library project.

**Update #1.**

An Android project and a GWT project use the library.

**Update #2 (it works for the Android project).**

I have successfully added a JAR to the Android project.

1. I edited a class in the library project.
2. I exported the library to a JAR.
3. I manually copied the JAR to the Android project's directory.
4. I can use the last changes of my library in the Android project.

The guides were helpful.

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337933/1065835

Comment: Have you considered using Maven, or some other similar tool?

Comment: @AdamArold, not yet. If it can solve the question, I'll learn a tool.

Comment: If one project depends on another one and they are in the same workspace, you don't have to use a .jar, just add the project under Properties > Java Build Path > Projects

Comment: @Guillaume, unfortunately, it doesn't work for my Android project. I ran into `NoClassDefFoundError`. After reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001414/1065835) and [this](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) I copied the JAR to `libs` folder and made it work.

Comment: @Red Planet this seems to be Android specific, you should rewrite your question and make it clear that this is an android project.

Comment: @Guillaume, I have got the Android project and a GWT project which use the same classes. And OK, I'll update the question.