# ClassDefNotFound exception using android library project as reference

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-library

I have an android library project and I want to reference it from another project.
The library project contains activities and xml layouts.
I have added its reference as following
MyProject properties-->Java Build Path--> projects like this
[image]

and in order and exports its listed like this

[image]

but when I try to call an activity from referenced project, I get exception, and here is the stacktrace

```
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jp.co.kom.android.ezimage.EZImageActivity
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at com.example.ezimgtest.MainActivity.openEZImage(MainActivity.java:56)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at com.example.ezimgtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4234)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17363)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4970)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-05 15:01:20.246: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why dont you use android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your activity EZImageActivity is declared in liberary manifest.Actual case androidManifest.xml merging is supported in version 20 of the ADT tools.
Enable with the manifestmerger.enabled property.

[more details](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included that class in manifest.

Also check the following answer,

[NoClassDefFoundError for code in an Java library on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android)

Comment: Do I need to add all activities of referenced project to my current project's manifest ?

Comment: Not current project's manifest but the library project's manifest

Comment: I have added all activities of library project in its manifest file

Comment: Please check this answer as well. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994715/noclassdeffounderror-on-external-library-project-for-android