# Android - ClassNotFoundException for library xmlns

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I have a library project that located in :Project/extralibs/ folder.

now I have this view in xml :

```
  <com.winsontan520.WScratchView
        xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scratch_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        wsv:antiAlias="true"
        wsv:overlayColor="#0000ff"
        wsv:revealSize="20dp"
        wsv:scratchable="true" />
```

And now I`m getting "No resource identifier found for attribute.." error.
I tried to change the path of xmlns to /lib/lib-auto and to the library path but getting ClassNotFoundException after running it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994715/noclassdeffounderror-on-external-library-project-for-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to build the external jar. Try removing it from your build path and follow these steps:

1. Create a folder in the root of your Android project called libs.
2. Add the jar to that folder.
3. Right-click the jar and click to add to build path.
4. Clean your project and try it again.

Comment: its a library project. not jar file

Comment: so you can import into your project simply link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project   OR  another solution  you can simply create a library project and put your library project in this project... see link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063826/how-to-create-jar-for-android-library-project

Comment: I work with android studio. Sorry if I'm missing something, but the library is imported as it should be in Android Studio and I'v done that many times this way.